# Message routing in websphere MQ cluster

Tags: routes, message, ibm-mq

Can websphere MQ cluster route messages to different Queues based on some MQMD characteristic?

Today we are using an application program to read messages from an MQ and load them to multiple MQs for parallel processing (based on DB2 table partitions to avoid contention).

We are interested in MQ functionality to transfer messages arriving in an MQ/ cluster to be routed to different destinations.

Answer (score 1):

> Can websphere MQ cluster route messages to different Queues based on
>   some MQMD characteristic?

No.  That is the job of the Integration Bus (Message Broker).

There is an open source project called Message Router (MRTR) (http://www.capitalware.com/mrtr_overview.html) that will route messages based on a keyword in the message data.  It would be very simple to modify it to look for value in an MQMD field.